# std::vector Error shows up: "Cannot increment a vector past the end", while wanting to erase specific element

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

I have a vector of classes, the class has a string name, among other private fields.

I want to implement a `void delete(string name)` function, which looks for the element based on the string (each class in a vector has a unique name).

However after simple testing, it gives me an error "Cannot increment past the end".

This is my function:

```
void delete_member(string member_name)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (auto it = member_list.begin(); it != member_list.end(); ++it, ++count)
        if (it->get_name() == member_name)
            member_list.erase(member_list.begin() + count);
}
```

As far as I have searched for an answer, it seems that the iterator shouldn't go past the .end() of the vector.

What is the flaw here? I am using the same loop to iterate over a vector for add_member(Member m) function which works completely fine

Comment: `it` gets invalidated after the call to erase, so you cannot continue to iterate aftewards. 
Either add a `break;` when you find the element or reassign `it` to the result of `erase`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invalidating `it` when you `erase`, so later uses of it are undefined, including incrementing and comparing it in the loop test.

You *could*

```
for (auto it = member_list.begin(); it != member_list.end(); )
    if (it->get_name() == member_name)
        it = member_list.erase(it);
    else
        it++
```

However there is a standard `<algorithm>` for this.

```
auto pred = [&](auto & member){ return member.get_name() == member_name; };
auto new_end = std::remove_if(member_list.begin(), member_list.end(), pred);
member_list.erase(new_end, member_list.end());
```

In C++20, it will be even easier

```
auto pred = [&](auto & member){ return member.get_name() == member_name; };
std::erase_if(member_list, pred);
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that you erase the element but you do not update the iterators. To avoid dealing with those, it is better to use STL algorithms. The standard usage is as follows

Pre C++20

```
member.erase(std::remove_if(member.begin(), member.end(), [&](const auto& val) 
{
  return val.get_name() == member_name;
}), member.end());
```

In C++20

```
std::erase_if(member, [&](const auto& val) 
{
  return val.get_name() == member_name;
});
```